# how to print the combination in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, apriori

I have data code conatin data like this

> dat<-data.frame(A=c("V1","V2","V3","V4"), B=c("V1","V2","V3","V5"))

I would like to take combination of each one and print output as

output of A

> V1=>V2V3V4
>
> V2=>V1V3V4
>
> V3=>V1V2V4
>
> V1V2=>V3V4
>
> V1V3=>V2V4
>
> V3V4=>V1V2
>
> V2V4=>V1V3
>
> V2V3V4=>V1
>
> V1V3V4=>V2
>
> V1V2V4=>V3

similar way B combination
my code is

```
vd<-data.frame()
vd<-data.frame(A=c("V1","V2","V3","V4"),B=c("V1","V2","V3","V4")) 
vf<-length(vd)
i<-1
while(i<=vf)
{
vd<-dat[,i]
leng<-nrow(dat)
selectru<-combn(vd,leng)
fst<-selectru[i]
select<-data.frame()
select<-selectru[selectru[,1]!=selectru[i],]
m<-length(select)
select<-combn(select,m)
snd <-apply(select,2,function(rows) paste0(rows, collapse = ""))
cat(sprintf("\"%s\" =>\"%s\"\n", fst, snd))
i<-i+1
}
```

this code is not working. I cant store multiple combination in single `data.frame`. thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output seems a bit strange (multiple combinations are the same), but I understand it might be hard to explain what you want. The following code might give you some inspiration. It takes all combinations and in front of the `=>` it shows whats not included in that combination.

```
dat<-data.frame(A=c("V1","V2","V3","V4"),B=c("V1","V2","V3","V4")) 
for (h in 1:ncol(dat)) {
  for (i in 1:(nrow(dat)-1)) {
    combinations1 <- combn(nrow(dat), i)

    for (j in 1:ncol(combinations1)) {
      k <- combinations1[,j]
      a <- (dat[k,h])
      a <- paste(a, sep="", collapse="") 
      b <-(dat[-k,h])
      b <- paste(b, sep="", collapse="") 
      cat(sprintf("\"%s\" =>\"%s\"\n", a, b))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am really sorry.there is no repeating combination.I corrected that

Comment: its working..your great.thanks.Actually there no repetition in data set and combination.

Comment: is it possible to save these printing values

Comment: yes its possible:

d=character()
dat<-data.frame(A=c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5"),B=c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V5")) 
for (h in 1:ncol(dat)) {
  for (i in 1:(floor(nrow(dat)/2))) {
    combinations1 <- combn(nrow(dat), i)
     
    for (j in 1:ncol(combinations1)) {
      k <- combinations1[,j]
      a <- (dat[k,h])
      a <- paste(a, sep="", collapse="") 
      b <-(dat[-k,h])
      b <- paste(b, sep="", collapse="") 
      c <-sprintf("\"%s\" =>\"%s\"\n", a, b)
      d <- c(d, c)
      fileConn<-file("output.txt")
      writeLines(d, fileConn)
      close(fileConn)
      
      
    }
  }
}

Comment: just copy the code. It saves your data to the file called **output.txt**

Comment: okay.i meant,is it possible to save the printed value in any data structure as same format(printed format).

Comment: From the variable d ;i can get the out put.is it possible to remove that punctuation before entering into d

Comment: what punctation do you mean?

Comment: "\"V1\" =>\"V2V3V4V5\"\n" "\"V2\" =>\"V1V3V4V5\"\n" "\"V3\" =>\"V1V2V4V5\"\n" "\"V4\" =>\"V1V2V3V5\"\n"

d contain values in this format.

Comment: i need only  "V1"=>"V2V3V4V5" v2="V1V3V4V5" etc..how can i elimate that \" and all that.using str_replace_all or any other method ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46160/discussion-between-user3090597-and-mehdi-nellen)

Comment: ahh yes that is because I think you used `print(d)` which prints out every hidden character you have to use `cat(d)` or `writeLines(d)`